# MySQL user variable based on calculation remains NULL while column has results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with gas consumption readings and all kinds of data required to analyse gas consumption. I'm trying to use SQL to perform calculations and provide a response that I can feed to a graph generator.

Right now I'm struggling with saving the result of a calculation as a variable for use farther down the query: `@corrConsGas`. The calculation itself is working fine and returns a column with the right data, but the variable remains NULL.

`corrConsGas` also seems to be skipping the first day of the range. I confirmed this by grouping and ordering the results by year, month & day. `corrConsGas` was 0.000 for the first date. I have no clue as to why.

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") as "Month",

   -- Calculate avg gas consumption on non-heating days (when degrDays = 0), i.e. avg gas used for showering etc
   -- Uses data from >= 2018-06-11, as no decimals were reported before that date...
   @avgNHConsGas := (SELECT AVG(`consGas`) FROM `energyTST` WHERE degrDays = 0 AND consGas > 0 AND DATE >= '2018-06-11') AS "avgNHConsGas",

   -- Uncorrected values
   sum(`degrDays`) as "degrDays",
   sum(`consGas`) as "consGas",
   IF( SUM(`consGas`) > 0, ROUND( SUM(`consGas`) / SUM(`degrDays`), 3), 0 ) AS "consDD",


   -- Corrected gas consumption and consumption per degree day. Produces 0 instead of negative consumption.
   -- Skips first day in range...why???
   @corrConsGas := CASE
       WHEN SUM(`consGas`) - SUM(@avgNHConsGas) > 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(`consGas` - @avgNHConsGas), 3)
       ELSE 0
   END AS "corrConsGas",

   -- calculate corrected gas consumption per degree day.
   -- @corrGasCons == NULL...why???
   SUM(@corrConsGas) / SUM(`degrDays`) AS corrConsDD,
   @corrConsGas +2 AS "TEST",


   -- Calculate corrConsGas again to calculate corrected gas consumption per degree day (corrConsGasDD).
   IF( SUM(`consGas` - @avgNHConsGas) > 0, ROUND(SUM(`consGas` - @avgNHConsGas) / SUM(`degrDays`), 3), 0 ) AS "corrConsGasDD"


   FROM `energyTST`
   WHERE date >= '2018-02-01' AND date <= '2018-04-30'
   GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
   ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Dates are all stored as date and formatted as YYYY-MM-DD without time data, all other data is stored as decimal(32,3).

In case anyone has a similar question; I finally solved it by using `INNER JOIN` to include the calculations in a column instead of using variables:

```
SELECT
   e1.date,

   -- Weighted degree days
   SUM(e2.wDegrDays) AS "wDegrDays",

   -- Gas usage based on daily usage minus average daily usage for showering
   SUM(IF(e1.consGas - e3.avgSU > 0, e1.consGas - e3.avgSU, 0)) AS "corrConsGas",

   -- Gas usage per degree day
   SUM(IF(e1.consGas - e3.avgSU > 0, e1.consGas - e3.avgSU, 0)) / SUM(e2.wDegrDays) AS "corrConsGasDD"

FROM 
   energyTST AS e1

   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT
         date,

         -- Degree days is the difference between daily mean temperature indoor (dmtI) and daily mean temperature outdoor (dmtO).
         -- They are weighed based on the month to account for weather influences (Nov-Feb * 1.1, Apr-Sept * 0.8)
         -- and only calculated when the dmtO is below the heating threshold, otherwise there are 0 degree days.
         CASE
            WHEN MONTH(date) IN (04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09) THEN ROUND(IF(dmtO < ht, dmtI - dmtO, 0) * 0.8, 3)
            WHEN MONTH(date) IN (11, 12, 01, 02) THEN ROUND(IF(dmtO < ht, dmtI - dmtO, 0) * 1.1, 3)
            ELSE ROUND(IF(dmtO < ht, dmtI - dmtO, 0), 3)
         END AS "wDegrDays"

      FROM energyTST
      ) AS e2 ON e1.date = e2.date

   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT

         -- Average usage on non-heating days = average daily shower usage
         ROUND(AVG(consGas), 3) AS "avgSU"

      FROM energyTST
      WHERE degrDays = 0 AND consGas > 0 AND date >= '2018-06-11'
      ) AS e3

WHERE e1.date >= '2018-02-01' AND e1.date <= '2018-02-28'
GROUP BY YEAR(e1.date), MONTH(e1.date), DAY(e1.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(e1.date), MONTH(e1.date), DAY(e1.date)
```

Comment: Use subqueries or CTEs, if you want to reuse calculated columns. Something like `@corrConsGas := SUM(..) as corrConsGas, SUM(@corrConsGas)` will not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul's comment indicated, you should just be able use a subquery like so:

```
... energyTST 
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT AVG(`consGas`) AS "avgNHConsGas"
   FROM `energyTST` 
   WHERE degrDays = 0 AND consGas > 0 AND DATE >= '2018-06-11'
) AS a
```

and then replace all references to `@avgNHConsGas` with `a.avgNHConsGas`

The order of evaluation and assignment of expressions involving @/session variables is not always clear; queries involving aggregation are one of those cases.

Comment: CROSS JOIN did not work, or at least I did not get it to work as needed. I finally ended up using 2 INNER JOIN with their own SELECT to perform the calculations and managed to get everything I need. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!